# Microsoft Bot: Offline DirectLine GSS Unable to post activity and receive data back

Tags: node.js, emulation, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have created a Microsoft bot on-premise (i.e. Hosted bot in IIS and Used Offline Directline for emulation using node package offline-directline-gss).

I am able to chat with the service but the issue I am facing is, since 'ConversationUpdate' doesn't work in webchat, I am posting the activity of type 'conversationupdate', text 'conversationupdate' on page load, and in the bot solution's Post method, I wrote a condition to check if activity.text is equal to 'conversationupdate' and wrote code to send a welcome message. But this is not happening.

In the command prompt which runs index.js, I can see the activity getting posted but the bot solution is not returning anything (or) something.

**This the html page code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
    <meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
        <link href="BotChat/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="bot"/>
    <script src="Masterfiles/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="BotChat/botchat.js"></script>

            <script>
        $(window).on('load', function () {
            try
            {
                botWindowExpandAndCollapse();
            }
            catch(err)
            {
                console.log(err.message);
            }                       
    });

      function botWindowExpandAndCollapse()
        {
            try
            {

            var directLine = new BotChat.DirectLine({
                        secret: params['s'],
                        user: user,
                        bot: bot,
                        token: params['t'],
                        domain: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/directline',
                        webSocket: false // defaults to true
                    });

            directLine
            .postActivity({ type: "conversationupdate", from: user, user:user, text:"conversationupdate"})
            .subscribe(id => alert("Conversation updated"));

                $('#bot .wc-chatview-panel').css('height','50px');
                $('#bot .wc-chatview-panel').addClass('IconView');
                //Script to hide
                $( "<span class='DPfigure need-help'>Need Help</span>" ).insertAfter( ".wc-chatview-panel" );
                if ($(".wc-chatview-panel").hasClass("fullHeight")) 
                {
                    $(".need-help").hide();
                    $('#bot .wc-chatview-panel').css('right','17px');
                }
                else
                {
                    $(".need-help").show();
                    $('#bot .wc-chatview-panel').css('right','105px');
                }


                $('.DPfigure').click(function(){
                    $('#bot .wc-chatview-panel').toggleClass('fullHeight');
                    $('#bot .wc-chatview-panel').toggleClass('IconView');
                    if ($(".wc-chatview-panel").hasClass("fullHeight")) 
                    {
                        $(".need-help").hide();
                        $('#bot .wc-chatview-panel').css('right','17px');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(".need-help").show();
                        $('#bot .wc-chatview-panel').css('right','105px');
                    }
                });
            }
            catch(err)
            {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        }


                var params = BotChat.queryParams(location.search);
    debugger;
                var user = {
                    id: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7),
                    name: params["username"] || 'username'
                    };

                var bot = {
                    id: params['botid'] || 'botid',
                    name: params["botname"] || 'botname'
                };

                window['botchatDebug'] = params['debug'] && params['debug'] === "true";

                    BotChat.App({
                    directLine: {
                        secret: params['s'],
                        token: params['t'],
                        domain: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/directline',
                        webSocket: false // defaults to true
                    },
                    user: user,
                    bot: bot,
                    locale: params['locale'],
                    resize: 'detect'
                    // sendTyping: true,    // defaults to false. set to true to send 'typing' activities to bot (and other users) when user is typing
                }, document.getElementById("bot"));

            </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**This is the index.js code:**

```
const url = require("url");
const directline = require("offline-directline-gss/dist/bridge");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const config = {
    localDirectLine: {
            hostUrl: "http://localhost",
            port: "3000"
        },
    apbots:[
        {
            botId:"TestingBot",
            botUrl:"http://localhost:3374/api/messages",
            "msaAppId": "",
            "msaPassword": ""
        },
    ]
};

directline.initializeRoutes(app, config);
```

**command prompt indicating post message is successful:**

[image: command prompt indicating post message is successful]

Can anyone please throw some light on what could be the reason for this. Thank You!

Comment: I don't understand one thing, you said `I am posting the activity of type 'event', text 'conversationupdate' on page load` but you are sending an `type: "conversationupdate"` so it's not an event

Comment: @NicolasR Sorry, Typo mistake. updated the query.

Comment: Did you already made the update? Can't see it. By the way, if the typo is also in your code, can you check again and make a new screen capture?

Comment: @NicolasR Found the issue. It was because of the directline object i wrote before posting the activity. Since, it is already present in the botchat configuration, issue is coming. I still don't know why declaring a varible and using it for the post activity causing a problem. For now, I removed the var directLine, in botWindowExpandAndCollapse() function which resolved the issue.

Comment: Glad you fixed it

Comment: @Bhargav, while I am glad you got it fixed, it would be nice to have the final working solution posted here.